# Flex Builder cannot locate the required version of flash player

Tags: apache-flex, flex-builder-3

I am new to Flex development. I got an error when i tried to run the application as Flex Builder cannot locate the require version of flash player and saying you might need to install flash player 9.

I am using Flex Builder 3 with SDK 3.2 and having latest flash player of version 11.1.162

Even having latest version of flash player why i could not able to run the application?

To run successfully what should i need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the error?  Are you trying to debug w/ a non-debug version of the Flash Player?

Comment: hi flextras, thnks 4 ur reply.. i could not able to upload the screenshot as it saying "Earn more than 10 reputation to post images". no i got debug version version of flash player (installed "flashplayer_11_ax_debug_32bit" and "flashplayer_11_plugin_debug_32bit").. any suggestions?

Comment: im getting error message as "Flex Builder cannot locate the required version of Flash Player. You might need to install Flash Player 9 or reinstall Flex Builder.

Do you want to try to run your application with the current version?"

Comment: I get this error only when I try to run Flex application inside the internal Flash Builder web browser. Changing the browser to external usually fix it for me.

Comment: hi 2DH, thnks 4 ur reply.. pls find my answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the above mentioned problem, when i have setting as "default system web browser" check box selected under Windows->Preferences->General->Web Browser in flex builder. Now i changed my settings by selecting the appropriate web browser from the list in which i want to run my application., in my case i selected Internet Explorer. After performing this i am able to run my application without any problem.

Comment: i tried this in my computer, but its not working, any other ideas you have, please let me know. I was working on Windows 10 machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this solution worked for me.
Do a search for NPSWF32.DLL and locate the most recent match on the list... on my system that was in

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Resources.
```

Copy that file to the folder it is complaining it can't find it in.

```
c:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins\
```

or

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Plugins\
```

You might need to create the Plugins directory.
Once you've done that, it should stop complaining.